# Set width of sap.m.MenuButton

Tags: css, sapui5

I have a `MenuButton`  https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.MenuButton/samples
in a bar with long `text` property value.

I would like to set `width` of the `MenuButton` in order to show all the text.
If I set `width` property, I can set (reduce) length (2px, 5px, 15px...) but increasing over a threshold the button remain to a fixed max size.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of an overkill but if you want to avoid using custom CSS classes, you could wrap the `MenuButton` with a flexbox control (with `renderType="Bare"`) and override max-width (or set min-width) by using [FlexItemData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FlexItemData.html#constructor) as a `layoutData`.

```
<HBox renderType="Bare">
  <MenuButton text="Hello World" width="600px">
    <layoutData>
      <FlexItemData maxWidth="100%"/>
    </layoutData>
  </MenuButton>
</HBox>
```

[image: Overriding max-width of sap.m.MenuButton with FlexItemData]

---

PS: The max-width of sap.m.MenuButton was indeed not documented. After filing an [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1310#issue-202424059), the API reference now mentions that it has a max-width.

> As per visual design this width can be maximum of 12rem (192px)